# Weird distortions when rigged object collides with itself

Tags: modeling, rigging, faces, collision

[image]

I've got this shape that I've rigged that I want to grow up and fold out like a branch.
But whenever it collides with itself I get what looks like faces forming between them.  Why does this happen and is there a way I can remedy this?

Comment: Possibly a problem with the collision, especially if the side is just one big face. It'll need vertices in the middle of the side faces as support.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! The problem seemed to be I had removed the edges to reduce polygon count. I rigged my older model and the problem wasn't there.